# Api name for Mobile User field in User detail page

Tags: user-record

I need to turn off Mobile User flag on Users for some profile. I am not able find the Api name for that to execute that through script. Please let me know anyone has idea on that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_user.htm

The field is called `UserPermissionsMobileUser`.